# TypeLoadException while creating type via TypeBuilder in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I am having trouble with understeanding exception thrown by CreateType method.
Exception and second question are at the end.

Code looks as follows :

Definitions (works - I hope) :

```
AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName("MyOwnNewAssembly"); 
AssemblyBuilder builder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = builder.DefineDynamicModule("Emission", "Emission.dll"); 
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("User", TypeAttributes.Public);
typeBuilder.SetParent(typeof(object)); 
var field = typeBuilder.DefineField("name", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Private);
```

Constructor creation (works):

```
var constructor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Any, new Type[] { typeof(String) });
var baseConstructor = typeof(object).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[0], null);var genertaor = constructor.GetILGenerator();
genertaor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);         
genertaor.Emit(OpCodes.Call, baseConstructor);  
genertaor.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
genertaor.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
genertaor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);  
genertaor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);  
genertaor.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);  
genertaor.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

And now here is code which doesn't work - overriding ToString:

```
var method = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");
var toStringBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("ToString", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);
typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(toStringBuilder, method);
var generator2 = toStringBuilder.GetILGenerator();
generator2.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
generator2.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); 
generator2.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
generator2.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
generator2.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
generator2.Emit(OpCodes.Ret,field);
```

and creating type (works):

```
typeBuilder.CreateType();
builder.Save("Emission.dll");
```

Here is code wich I am trying to create :

```
public class User{
   private string _name;
   public User(string name){
      _name = name;
   }
   public override string ToString(){
      return _name;
   }
}
```

After decompilation above ToString looks like :

```
.method public hidebysig virtual 
instance string ToString () cil managed 
{
.maxstack 1
.locals init (
[0] string
)
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldarg.0
IL_0002: ldfld string AssemblyBuilding.User::_name
IL_0007: stloc.0
IL_0008: br.s IL_000a

IL_000a: ldloc.0
IL_000b: ret
} // end of method User::ToString
```

And my **other question** is why

```
    IL_0007: stloc.0
    IL_0008: br.s IL_000a

    IL_000a: ldloc.0
```

doesn't looks like this (why there is a jump) :

```
IL_0007: stloc.0
IL_000a: ldloc.0
```

Exception is :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match. Type: 'User'. Assembly: 'MyOwnNewAssembly,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

**UPDATE:**
I corrected upper code with string returning function. And now it almost works but I am getting yet another exception indicating that ToString is not virtual.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Method 'ToString' in type 'User' from assembly MyOwnNewAssembly,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' must be virtual in order to implement the method in the interface or supertype.

Then I changed method name from "ToString" to "Object.ToString" but the same exception appears.

**UPDATE 2**
I figured what was the problem. Method builder should have more MethodAttributes as shown here:

```
            var toStringBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("ToString", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: The return type of your `ToString` seems to be missing

Comment: @C.Evenhuis See my edit if you please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter in your `typeBuilder.DefineMethod()` call should be `typeof(string)` and not `null` because `ToString()` returns a string.

The branch was most likely introduced by the compiler for a debug build.